withQueryString() does not work with eager loading and pagination
I'm trying to use withQueryString() to $users
$users = $usersQuery->paginate(10);
like this
$users = $usersQuery->paginate(10)->withQueryString();
But I got an error 'Undefined method withQueryString()'
This is my code
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $usersQuery = User::with('userType');

        // Filter by name
        if ($request->name != null) {
            $usersQuery->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->name . '%');
        }

        // Filter by role
        if ($request->user_type_id != null) {
            $usersQuery->where('user_type_id', $request->user_type_id);
        }

        // Filter by role
        if ($request->suspended != null) {
            $usersQuery->where('suspended', $request->suspended);
        }

        $users = $usersQuery->paginate(10);

        return view('admin.users.index', [
            'users' => $users,
            'title' => 'Users'
        ]);
    }

If i use withQueryString without on User::paginate(10) without eager loading it has no errors. Any thoughts on how to resolve this? I'm using Laravel 11

Can you try :     $users = $usersQuery->paginate(10)->withQueryString(); just to see if that works. If that works I can respond your question with a little explanation.

If I'm not wrong the Undefined method withQueryString() is only happening in your IDE not when running it. It is normal since the $userQuery->paginate() returns Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator that is defined inside its docblock, but if you look at its definition or in vscode you ctrl+left-click it you will see that it will return a Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginatorwhich extends theIlluminate\Pagination\AbstractPaginator where you can find the withQueryString(). But if you are bothered by the red underline in the withQueryString() you can just use the appends() which the withQueryString() using under the hood.
$data = $userQuery->paginate();
$data->appends($request->query());

It will add all the URL query in the pagination links.
